# Equivalent Switch 4A 1/3 HP for hedge trimmer

Tags: switches

My hedge trimmer died (Bosch 7000 Pro). Switch not working properly (spongy and no audible click). Need to replace.

Question: I can't find this switch anywhere! Are there equivalents I could use? I'm not sure what the 4A 1/3 HP means, as there aren't any components inside the switch. I assume it means how much current can pass through the switch safely?

Anyway, I've found 16A switches on ebay but really not sure what switch I could get to replace this one.

Thanks for your time
[image: Cherry switch]

Answer (score 3):

That looks like an ordinary 27.8 x 15.9mm microswitch. You can easily find one that fits, has the same 6.3mm terminals and is rated for the current specified.

**However**, the contact gap is specified as >3mm which is very unusual (most are 1mm or even 0.5mm), so it is well suited for relatively low-current high inductance loads. (Especially) if your mains is 240VAC, I think it might be worth seeking out the original replacement. If you choose not to , I would suggest getting a quality switch such as [Omron](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-v.pdf) that has a 1/3 HP 250VAC rating and will be less likely to burst into flames if it arcs internally.

Comment: This part number only specifies 1/2 Hp yet has 4 current ratings for these from 10A to 21A which depends on the load. I would use the 16A rated.  with 40A surge rating as start can be as much as 8 to 10x RMS load or 4A motor steady RMS These are also only 1mm. I did not see 3mm for the motor safety rated switches  N.B.  The voltage rating is less important that the stored L energy and DCR start resistance of the motor.

Comment: Thank for your responses. I'm in Germany (mains 230V). I would very much like to replace the switch with the original, but I have been a unable to locate it. I'll keep looking. Just out of interest, does the (3) mean the contact gap? And what does the '136K' in the top right corner mean?

Comment: Would this be a suitable replacement?    https://www.tme.eu/de/en/details/d3v-16-3c5/microswitches-snap-action/omron-ocb/d3v163c5/

Answer (score 0):

Hedge trimmers are highly reactive generators with lots of stored energy when cut-off with no rated work load. This causes the contacts to  arc with high voltage from V=LdI/dt then it is extinguished within a certain number of cycles.

These motor types use switches that are derated to 25% of resistive rating, which is normal. (some may be 30% and also depends on start surge)

Thus I would expect a 16A switch to work.  But OEM's must get safety-certification for the application for UL approval for flammability.
Yours failed safely (so far) with spongy contacts.
BTW I have 3 electric hedge trimmers (donations)  They fail quickly with heavy loads especially on the cam slot and disk actuator.